# How to Update Account in StripeApi using C#?

Tags: c#, stripe.net

I am trying to update Account in `Stripe Api` using `Stripe.net`library ,using  `StripeAccountService` and storing it in `StripeAccount`class which i made by myself to store the result returned by API :

```
var accountService = new StripeAccountService("secretKey in string");
StripeRequestOptions option = new StripeRequestOptions();
option.StripeConnectAccountId = "AccountId to update";
StripeAccount x = accountService.Get(option);
x.Email = "Local@local.com";
//Then i do not know how to save changes back to api now.
```

But `StripeAccountService` class has no Update method define. How I can perform update on the Account.

I am using [this](https://github.com/jaymedavis/stripe.net) library. Stripe api does have an update method too [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/python#update_account).

Comment: In this example, are you trying to update the email in the account?

Comment: Yes, it is just demonstration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stripe.net doesnot support Managed account but it can be done using following approach it is for update account.

I won't be able to give code but can provide the correct approach, it is tested.

```
https://api.stripe.com/v1/account
```

is the **Url** for updating stripe account.

Now you need to add two header and a body you can try `WebRequest` or `httpclient` class.

The reason i am unable to provide code because i did not do any research in adding multiple headers and a body.

so it would look something like this

```
Header

Property          value
Authorization     bearer "SecretKey"
Stripe-Account    "acct_16uR8kKN01245679"

Body

Property         value
email            "test@test.com"
support_phone    "555-867-5309"
```

You can see complete property list [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_account). i picked few for demonstration purpose only.

Then save the response in any variable and it is done.

Answer (score 0):

Stripe.net does not support managed accounts: "Managed Accounts are a valuable service as well, but they are not available in Stripe.net yet." https://github.com/jaymedavis/stripe.net#stripe-connect